# How to code multiple button navigation with Java activities

Tags: java, android

Question 1: I have two activities. I was wondering how to optimize it. I can either create two activities with multiple listeners. Or create multiple Java files for each button(onclick listener)

Question 2: I have tried to create multiple listeners in one Java, but can only get one button to work. What is the syntax for multiple listeners in one Java file? Here is my *updated code: now the issue is no matter what button is clicked on it leads to the same page.

```
package install.fineline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Activity1 extends Activity2 {

    Button Button1;
    Button Button2;
    Button Button3;
    Button Button4;
    Button Button5;
    Button Button6;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fineline);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }


    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;
        Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.autobody);
        Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.glass);

        Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wheels);

        Button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speedy);

        Button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sevan);

        Button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.towing);

        Button6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### activity2.java

```
package install.fineline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    Button Button1;

    public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.autobody);
    }
    Button Button2;

    public void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.glass);
    }
    Button Button3;

    public void onCreate3(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wheels);
    }
    Button button4;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.speedy);
    }
    Button Button5;

    public void onCreate5(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sevan);
    }

    Button Button6;

    public void onCreate6(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.towing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, all your buttons are leading to the same page because you have the same code in each listener:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Where `Activity1.class` is the class object of the activity you wish to start. If you wanted to start `Activity2` from that button, you need to put `Activity2.class` as the second parameter to Intent.

In your Activity2 example, note that only onCreate() is going to get called, because that method overrides the onCreate() method in the Activity base class. onCreate1, onCreate2, etc. will never be called unless you call them explicitly, because they do not override anything in the base class.

As per your original question, it is fine to create the OnClickListeners inline as you're doing in Activity1, or you could create them as class variables for better organization, and to keep the amount of inline code to a minimum. For example:

```
OnClickListener button1Listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);   

    }

});
```

and then you can set your click listener as:

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(button1Listener);
```

I would consider creating a new .java file for every OnClickListener overkill.